# Is it possible to handle inputs and mouse movements outside of current tab or window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keylistener, mouselistener

I would like to create a simple productivity web page, It should be able to count the ACTIVE time spent on computer, so it should stop counting after a while without mouse movements, key pressed etc.. And start again to count when they happen..

Is it possible to do something like this with Javascript?

The user should just be able to open the website in a browser tab and the program should be able to track keys and mouse events at least inside the whole browser activity or (better) the whole user activity.

Comment: No, it's not !!

Comment: not with pure HTML/JS page, but you could make a browser extension for connection between the tabs. But it would only give you a tool to count time of activity inside the browser.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will follow this path.. It would be interesting anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers won't alow you becouse of security/privacy. You need to do this by native app for Windows, Linux etc.